# Does the "sheaf of diffeologically-smooth real-valued functions" functor reflect isomorphisms?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, ringed-spaces, synthetic-differential-geometry

(This is a follow-up question to [this earlier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477735/is-the-sheaf-of-diffeologically-smooth-real-valued-functions-functor-faithful).)

Setup: let $u : \mathrm{Diff} \rightarrow\mathrm{Set}$ denote the forgetful functor on the category of smooth manifolds.

Let $\tilde{X} \subset
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(u(-),X_{0})$ be a diffeology (per the [nLab definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diffeological+space#definition))
on a set $X_{0}$, called the "underlying set"
of $\tilde{X}$. Note $\tilde{X} \in \mathrm{Functors}(\mathrm{Diff}^{\mathrm{op}}\rightarrow \mathrm{Set})$.

- Let $X = \mathrm{Dtopology}(\tilde{X}) \in \mathrm{DTopologicalSpaces}$ be the underlying D-topological space of $\tilde{X}$ (cf. the above nLab page).

  Note $X$ is the topological space with underlying set $X_0$ of $\tilde{X}$, equipped with the final topology induced by all the maps $f\in\tilde{X}(M) \subset \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(uM,X_0)$ for all $M \in \mathrm{Diff}$.

  According to [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Delta-generated+topological+space#OnTopologicalHomotopyTypeAndDiffeologicalShape), the $X$ above is then a $\Delta$-generated topological space, or D-topological space or D-space for short.
- Let us define a presheaf $\mathcal{F}_{\tilde{X}}$ on $X$ via
  $$
  \mathcal{F}_{\tilde{X}}(U) = \left\{f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\,\big|\,
  \forall M \in \mathrm{Diff} , \forall g \in \tilde{X}(M) \subset \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(M,X_0) ,\,
  \bigl(\,g^{-1}(U)\xrightarrow{f\circ g} \mathbb{R} \text{ is smooth} \,\bigr)
  \right\}
  $$
  as a (unital) $\mathbb{R}$-algebra subpresheaf of the sheaf of continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $X$.
- The presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf and has local stalks, making $X$ a locally ringed space. Let us call $\mathcal{F}_{\tilde{X}}$ the "sheaf of diffeologically-smooth functions" on $X$.

Furthermore the above construction $\tilde{X} \mapsto (X,\mathcal{F}_{\tilde{X}})$
gives a functor
$$
\psi : \mathrm{DiffeologicalSpaces} \rightarrow \mathrm{LocallyRingedDSpaces}
$$

- Following an answer posted on the question linked at the top,
  we can see that $\psi$ is faithful. Indeed, the forgetful functor from RingedSpaces to Spaces, composed after $\psi$, equals the Dtopology functor $\mathrm{DiffeologicalSpaces} \xrightarrow{\tilde{X} \mapsto X} \mathrm{DSpaces}$, which the aforementioned answer shows is already faithful.

---

My question now is: does $\psi : \mathrm{DiffeologicalSpaces} \rightarrow \mathrm{LocallyRingedDSpaces}$ reflect isomorphisms? (Such functors are also called "[conservative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor#definition).")

I.e., if $\tilde{f} : \tilde{X} \rightarrow \tilde{Y}$ is a morphism of diffeological spaces, and $\psi(\tilde{f})$ is an isomorphism (in the category LocallyRingedSpaces), then is $\tilde{f}$ an isomorphism of diffeological spaces?

If I'm not mistaken, $\tilde{f}$ can be a non-isomorphism while $\mathrm{Dtopology}(\tilde{f}) = f : X\rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism. (So, the Dtopology functor does not reflect isomorphisms.)

---

(Edit: changed "detect" to "reflect" and added the nLab link.)

Comment: The term you are looking for is “reflects isomorphisms”. A functor $F$ reflects isomorphism if for all $f$, if $Ff$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification.